# sqldeveloper ORA-12505. TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer

There are similar [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/listener-refused-the-connection-with-following-error-ora-12505-tns-listener-d)[s](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13262/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript) asked and answered in this network related to the error message given in the question, however this problem is a little different from each.

I have installed oracle 12c in my ubuntu can successfully connect to my `hr` user with `sqlplus hr/hr@pdborcl` through command prompt.

```
oracle@ubuntu:~$ sqlplus hr/hr@pdborcl
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Nov 16 21:57:24 2015
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Last Successful login time: Mon Nov 16 2015 21:24:32 +05:45
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>show user;
USER is "HR"
```

I am however trying to use sqldeveloper for ease. In the create connection option in sqldeveloper when I give the following credentials

I get the following error. 
    [image]
    ORA-12505. TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

However connection with

Username: sys

Password: ******

SID:**orcl**

And same all other credentials work fine.

My tnsname.ora has

```
PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
   )
 )

ORCL =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
  )
 )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use Service Names to connect to Pluggable Databases in 12c.

It's just one of those things that can trip you up, I guess! SQL Plus connecting OK probably threw you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. And I solved it by using **SERVICE NAME** (an alias) instead of **SID**:

**1**. Open file **tnsnames.ora** from your *ORACLE_HOME* folder. In case you don't know its location, do the following steps

---

**Windows (open cmd)**

```
> sqlplus // connect to sqlplus, login as sysdba
 as / sysdba
 // then type your password that you set in configuration setup step
 // next 3 lines used for getting ORACLE_HOME
 > var OHM varchar2(100);
 > EXEC dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', :OHM);
 > PRINT OHM // ---> ORACLE_HOME
```

---

**Linux (open Terminal Ctrl+Alt+T)**

---

`echo $ORACLE_HOME`

**tnsnames.ora** is located at **[Your_ORACLE_HOME]/Network/Admin**. Open it with your editor.

**2**. In **tnsnames.ora** file, look for the line which contains the SERVICE_NAME

---

[image]

---

**3**. Select Service name and type above name, TEST success and **you've done**!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hostname also gives this error: Instead of writing localhost there, try to type your "COMPUTER name" (for example: if you PC name is User_PC)
write it User_PC
the rest leave default!

Answer (score -3):

You need to start the database to connect. Im using Express Edition 11g. I had faced the same problem. Problem disappears once you select Start Database option from Start>All Programs>Oracle 11g Express edition. Alternatively, you can go to the drive where you have installed oracle (in my case) D:/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/bin. Here you will find a Windows Batch File called StartDB. Double click on this and your database will start and your connections will test successfully.